# Add hours minutes with the format hh:mm using moment

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I am using moment library and from front end I am getting time in `HH:mm` I need to add hours and minutes to current time using moment.

Suppose I am getting `05:30` from the frontend and I need to add to the current UTC time. How can I do that using momentjs?

I tried that but didn't work

```
moment().add('05:30', 'HH:mm')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a [duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) for `'05:30'` using [`moment.duration(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/) and the use [`add(Duration)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/).

As moment duration docs states, `'05:30'` is a valid input for [`moment.duration(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/creating/):

> As of **2.1.0**, moment supports parsing ASP.NET style time spans. The following formats are supported.
>
> The format is an hour, minute, second string separated by colons like `23:59:59`. The number of days can be prefixed with a dot separator like so `7.23:59:59`. Partial seconds are supported as well `23:59:59.999`.

Here a live sample:

```js
const result = moment().add( moment.duration('05:30') );
console.log( moment().format() );
console.log( result.format() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: :O... Well, that's clever! Sounds like it's the best practice.

Comment: Hi VincenzoC I have this format `0530`. Now it is not working. Any idea?

Comment: `0530` is not in _ASP.NET style time spans_ supported by moment, since there are not colons (_The format is an hour, minute, second string **separated by colons**_), you have to add your own logic to translate the input according your needs. (e.g. `var input = '0530'; var output = str.substring(0, 2) + ':' + str.substring(2)`, but there could be a lot of corner cases)

Answer (score 3):

Moment have `.add`  property

moment().add(1, 'day')

Reference: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

For converting to specific format:

```
moment().add({hours:5, minutes: 30}).format('HH:mm')
```

Comment: @Profer If you already getting time in any format, then after adding any duration you will get the same format. Or you can add duration first and then convert to specific format.

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah i missed that. Updated answer

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: @VincenzoC above provided what I personally think is the best practice. Check this answer only as an alternative to his.

Just do:

```
moment().add({
   hours: 5,
   minutes: 30
});
```

As suggested in the official documentation: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Either use the object literal as above, or use chaining.

I you can't get rid of that string, just acquire hours and minutes by splitting:

```js
let [hours, minutes] = '05:30'.split(':').map(Number);
console.log(hours);
console.log(minutes);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var t = '05:30';
var hours = parseInt(t.substr(0,2));
var minutes = parseInt(t.substr(3,5));
moment().add(hours,'hours').add(minutes,'minutes');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`moment.add(5,'hours').add(30,'minutes').format('HH:mm')`

OR

`moment().add({hours:5, minutes: 30}).format('HH:mm')`